# Is there a font alternative to Mason Book?

Tags: font-recommendation

It looks like this:
[link](http://www.whatfontis.com/Mason-Book.font).

Anybody know of any alternative, commercial licensed fonts that are simplistic and semi-serifed?
Thanks!

EDIT (partial picture of the font) -

[image]

Comment: on the bottom of the page you provided there are alternative free fonts

Comment: Oh, shoot. Forget what I asked. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well, actually, none of those are for commercial-use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> simplistic and semi-serifed?

These are full serifs. The term is called ['slab-serif' or 'egyptian'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_serif). Lubalin Graph (as Ilan suggests) is perhaps the most iconic of the slab-serifs as it had heavy use thorughout the 70s and 80s. (It's named after its creator, [Herb Lubalin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Lubalin).)

But to answer the question, there are dozens of options. You can do a [search for slab-serif of myFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/slab+serif/fonts/) to see plenty of choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find an alternative on [Myfonts](http://www.myfonts.com/).

Look for these - probably some of the have smaller serifs, but this task is subjective, so probably you can choose the font yourself.

[image]